# Digamma series Representation

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, gamma-function, digamma-function

I was reading about where the series representation of digamma is proved and its states:

$$-\frac{1}{x}-\gamma +\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right) = -\gamma +\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x-1}\right) $$

I don't see where the $n+x-1$ comes from though any idea?

Comment: The correct formula is $\psi(s) = \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} = -\gamma + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+s}$. The proof is that $\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+s}$ is a bounded entire function, so by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) it is constant. And the constant is by definition $-\gamma$. Showing it is the same $\gamma$ as in $\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k})-\ln n$ requires a little more work.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't answer my question how the -1/x goes into the sum

Comment: you didn't read carefully what I wrote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good starting point is the [Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass.27s_definition):
$$ \Gamma(x) = \frac{e^{-\gamma x}}{x}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{x/n}\tag{1} $$
By considering $\frac{d}{dx}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides,
$$ \psi(x) = -\frac{1}{x}-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x}{n(n+x)}=-\frac{1}{x}-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right).\tag{2} $$
Since $x\,\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$, that can be written also as:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right) = \gamma+\psi(x+1).\tag{3}$$
Anyway, your concern is simply addressed by noticing that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n+x-1}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\tag{4}$$ since the LHS is a telescopic series.

Comment: Could you explain how you got 3?

Comment: @jakewalsh: $x\,\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$ implies $$\frac{1}{x}+\psi(x)=\psi(x+1)$$ through logarithmic differentiation.